# Maintain relationship between cells even after adding more rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to correct numerous spelling and data entry deficiencies in a text file.

The raw data is imported with a script into another sheet and column O is populated with  =sort(unique(filter(othersheet!D2:D,othersheet!D2:D<>""))).

The inputted data can change because it is constantly being added to.
Cells in Column P are manually validated from the list in Column Q.
Any new items are added to Column Q as needed.

So, as the list in Column O changes, the manual validations in Column P are no longer related to the matching item in Column O.

How do I maintain the relationship between the manual validation and the constantly changing positions of the data?
I've tried linking with hash numbers, or keeping a fixed list of relationships, but it would add so many multiples of the data that it would become unmanageable.
I'm ok with using scripts or formulas or a combination.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: the only good way to maintain the relationship between static data and dynamic data is to invest in a database.  There are dozens of online database companies that do exactly what you're hoping to do with cobbled together scripts and half-measures.  Spreadsheets and databases are different, and when you try to use one to do what the other is good at, you can paint yourself into a corner.

Comment: Ain't that the truth!
And that's exactly why I'm asking - I'm in a corner and I'm too stubborn to leave it and move on.
So, thank you, you've given me the push I needed.

Comment: ha, we've all been there Frank! good luck, and maybe post back here in the future with whatever database you end up using so that others who come across this thread might learn from your example!